# SharePoint 2013 Calendar colour using JavaScript/jquery

Tags: sharepoint-server, jquery, sharepoint-calendar

I have a requirement where I have a custom SharePoint 2013 list and a calendar view for the list.

I want the calendar items to be coloured based on some status. But there are hundreds of status and hence I can not use the colorOverlay.

So I would like achieve this using javascript/jquery. I have referred below link and it doesn't work for me. https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/office/SharePoint-2010-Calendar-cd15fd51

Any alternative way using javascript / jquery ?

Comment: what SP version are you using? We achieved creating our colored calendar, but we had to put name of status in the calendar, it had to be visible. If it is acceptable for you, I can put explanation in answer.

Comment: @DaniloKorac No i don not want to show the status. and I am using SP2013